# $f(f(f(a)))=a$ but $f(f(a))\ne a$ how many function similar exists?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let A be a set, $|A|=12$ 
let $f$ be a function from $A$ to $A$ ($f:A\to A$ )
For each $a\in A$ 
 $f(f(f(a)))=a$ 
But $f(f(a))\ne a$ 
$f$ is bijection,
How many similar functions exist?

I am not sure how to solve this, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A=\{1,2,3\}$ And take $A$ be $(1,2)(2,3)(3,1)$. A satifies the requirements. What you want is for the function to be composed entirely of three-cycles. That is you want that if $f(a)=b$ then $f(b)=c$ with $c\neq b$. And you want $f(c)=a$.

When $|A|=12$ you want to see how many permutations consisting of four $3$-cycles exist.To do this notice there are $\frac{1}{4!}\binom{12}{3,3,3,3}=\frac{12!}{6*6*6*6*24}=15400$ ways to select the elements in each cycle, and then each cycle admits two orientations. Hence you want $2^4\times 15400=246400$.

Comment: sorry for my stupidty, why there are four 3-cycles exist? because there are $f(a)=b$ , $f(b)=c$  , $c\neq b$ , $f(c)=a$ 4 conditions?

Comment: You might want to read up a little on cycle decomposition for permutations.

Comment: The multinomial coefficient $\binom{12}{3,3,3,3}$ tells you how many ways to select a red team, a blue team , a green team and a yellow team, each consisting of $3$ students, when there are $12$ students to chose from. We have to divide this by $4!$ since we do not care which is the first cycle, which is the second.... Therefore there are $\frac{1}{4!}\binom{12}{3,3,3,3}$ ways to split the $12$ elements into four groups of $3$.

Comment: I replaced it. Why do you say that?

Answer (score 3):

Such an $f$ is a bijection $f:\>[12]\to[12]$ and as such is a product of cycles.  Since $f^{\circ3}={\rm id}$ only $3$-cycles and $1$-cycles (fixed points) are allowed. When $a\in[12]$ is a fixed point then $f\bigl(f(a)\bigr)=a$, which is forbidden. It follows that $f$ is a product of four $3$-cycles.

In how many ways can we form these four cycles?

One cycle contains $12$, and there are $11\cdot10$ ways to compose the cycle containing $12$.

Among the left over nine numbers one, say $m_1$, is largest, and there are $8\cdot 7$ ways to  compose the  cycle containing $m_1$.

Among the left over six numbers one, say $m_2$, is largest, and there are $5\cdot 4$ ways to  compose the  cycle containing $m_2$.

Among the left over three numbers one, say $m_3$, is largest, and there are $2\cdot 1$ ways to  compose the  cycle containing $m_3$.

It follows that the total number $N$ of bijections $f$ satisfying the given conditions is given by
$$N=11\cdot10\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot5\cdot 4\cdot  2\cdot 1=246\,400$$